Auto-py-to-exe does not open the py file in its directory
I need to open a file. Without auto-py-to-exe library everything works, exept of the function:
  def open_file(self):

        script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        internal_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, "_internal")
        file_path = os.path.join(internal_dir, "file.py")
        os.startfile(file_path)

I tried using subprocess.Popen, but that didn't work either.

so you are using auto-py-to-exe library and it stops the function, provided by you, from working?

Yes. I guess auto-py-to-exe cannot open another files or determine its own directory

please, provide what error or output you are getting

I don't have any output or error, the program just ignores the part with the function I gave. But if you add some code like
process_pid = os.getpid() subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/PID', str(process_pid)])
he processes it

you mean, if you add this line into the function?

yes. but only that part works
